# Cast a varchar to minutes, seconds and milliseconds time format?

Tags: mysql, time-format

I have a table where some fields contain time information, following the format minutes:seconds:milliseconds. For example: `1:38:096`.

Later on, I need to compare between some of this times and I can't do that if I handle them as `varchar`. How can I cast this strings to a manageable time format?

I have tried `time_format()` function but it does not support milliseconds according to the documentation and it's not working fine on my case.

How can I handle this?

Comment: Why? If it's a date or time it should be in the database in date or time format.

Comment: @user207421 that must be *the* most asked question in the various SQL tags...

Comment: I wrote up [bug 99621](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=99621) based on your description. If you find something not working as documented Oracle take bug reports from anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE("1:38:096", "%i:%s:%f");
```

Result

```
STR_TO_DATE("1:38:096", "%i:%s:%f")
00:01:38.096000
```

This is a DATETIME, but you can  extract minutes and use all other timefunction provided in the link